# SQL query for restoring the latest revision on all posts in wordpress

Tags: sql, wordpress

My wordpress site recently got attacked and all the posts seem to have been updated with a blank version. So I want to restore the most latest revision for all posts. (NB: In wordpress the current published version is also stored in the database as a revision. So I think I would need to restore the 2nd revision (when arranged in the descending order))

What would be the SQL query for that?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So, all you need is in your database (luckily). The posts themselves can be retrieved like this

```
global $wpdb;

$query = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'revision'";

$query_results = $wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_A);

foreach ($query_results as $q_key => $q_value) {
    $post = array(
      'post_content'            => $q_value['post_content']
      'post_name'               => $q_value['post_name']
      'post_title'              => $q_value['post_title']
      'post_status'             => $q_value['post_status']
      'post_type'               => 'post'
      'post_author'             => $q_value['post_author']
      'ping_status'             => $q_value['ping_status']
      'post_parent'             => $q_value['post_parent']
      'menu_order'              => $q_value['menu_order']
      'to_ping'                 => $q_value['to_ping']
      'pinged'                  => $q_value['pinged']
      'post_password'           => $q_value['post_password']
      'guid'                    => $q_value['guid']
      'post_content_filtered'   => $q_value['post_content_filtered']
      'post_excerpt'            => $q_value['post_excerpt']
      'post_date'               => $q_value['post_date']
      'post_date_gmt'           => $q_value['post_date_gmt']
      'comment_status'          => $q_value['comment_status']
    );  

    wp_insert_post( $post );
}
```

Read about [wp_insert_post()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) here.

Now, depending on how much posts you have, this can either take a while, or it can break. If it breaks, then you'll need to wrap this in a function that you'll call with AJAX. Something like this should do the trick:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_insert_posts', 'database_ajax_insert_posts' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_insert_posts', 'database_ajax_insert_posts' );

function database_ajax_insert_posts(){

    global $wpdb;

    $offset = $_POST['offset'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'revision' LIMIT $offset, 1";

    $query_results = $wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_A);

    foreach ($query_results as $q_key => $q_value) {
        $post = array(
          'post_content'            => $q_value['post_content']
          'post_name'               => $q_value['post_name']
          'post_title'              => $q_value['post_title']
          'post_status'             => $q_value['post_status']
          'post_type'               => 'post'
          'post_author'             => $q_value['post_author']
          'ping_status'             => $q_value['ping_status']
          'post_parent'             => $q_value['post_parent']
          'menu_order'              => $q_value['menu_order']
          'to_ping'                 => $q_value['to_ping']
          'pinged'                  => $q_value['pinged']
          'post_password'           => $q_value['post_password']
          'guid'                    => $q_value['guid']
          'post_content_filtered'   => $q_value['post_content_filtered']
          'post_excerpt'            => $q_value['post_excerpt']
          'post_date'               => $q_value['post_date']
          'post_date_gmt'           => $q_value['post_date_gmt']
          'comment_status'          => $q_value['comment_status']
        );  

        wp_insert_post( $post );
    }

}
```

And AJAX

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    "use strict";

    var offset = 1;

    function ajax_call(){

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: ajaxurl,
            data: {
                'action': 'insert_posts',
                'offset': offset,
            },
            success: function(response) {
                if (offset < 100){ //Number of posts go here
                    offset += 1;
                    ajax_call();
                } else{
                    $('#wpbody-content').append('<p>All done!</p>' );
                }
            },
            error : function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('#wpbody-content').html(jqXHR + ' :: ' + textStatus + ' :: ' + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }

    ajax_call();

});
```

Also be sure to localize your AJAX url with the handle of the script in which you'll put your AJAX call.

```
wp_localize_script('your_handle', 'db_from_WP', array(
    'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
));
```

Taxonomy should be in the database, and you could get them in a similar fashion.

This is not foolproof, but should work. The thing that I can see that could be a bit problematic is getting the right taxonomy for the post, but that is doable, although with a bit fiddling around.

Hope this helps.